# Monitor total internet used via router

Tags: router

I have a TP-Link TD-W8951ND ADSL router and I have a limited broadband plan and my ISP does not have an option to monitor how much data I have used. I have some 5-6 devices that I use internet on and I want to monitor the total internet used by all my devices. Now I also use my router for streaming videos using a SMB share and I don't want that to get into the readings. Is there any way to measure the total amount of internet data used by my router?

Comment: Have you looked into router's web-interface?

Comment: Yep it doesnt show bandwith usage